# sub total implementation using plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table like below, I need to get the subtotal for james and jones and overall total.

could some one help me to find the answer by only using plsql

```
order no | name | amount

order 1  | james | 400

order 2  | jones | 6000

order 3  | james | 100
```

o/p

```
order 1 | james | 400

order 3 | james | 6000

total   | null  | 6400

order 2 | jones | 100

overall  | null | 6500
```

Comment: Should there be one more total row (for jones)?

Comment: Why only using PL/SQL? Is this homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rollup`:

```
select 
  case grouping(order_no)+ grouping(name) 
    when 2 then 'overall'
    when 1 then 'total'
    else order_no
  end as order_no, 
  name,
  sum(amount) as amount
from t
group by rollup(name, order_no)
```

Produces:

```
order 1     james   400
order 3     james   100
total       james   500
order 2     jones   6000
total       jones   6000
overall             6500
```

Note that I've kept the name as is case of total so as to be able to tell which total is for which user.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/ZZTBDX56074)

Comment: can we do the same with plsql

Comment: Never do it PL/SQL when it can be done in SQL. SQL based solution will always be faster.

Comment: yes I agree,  but I want the plsql o/p for some reason

Comment: You can put the select query in a cursor and use it in PLSQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit silly, and I totally agree with Gurv here, but here is the solution using plsql and borrowing from GURV's solution.

```
create table mytable (
order_no varchar(30),
name varchar2(30),
amount number

)


Insert into MYTABLE (ORDER_NO,NAME,AMOUNT) values ('1','james',4000);
Insert into MYTABLE (ORDER_NO,NAME,AMOUNT) values ('2','jones',6000);
Insert into MYTABLE (ORDER_NO,NAME,AMOUNT) values ('3','james',6000);



DECLARE

CURSOR totalByPerson IS
select 
  case grouping(order_no)+ grouping(name) 
    when 2 then 'overall'
    when 1 then 'total'
    else order_no
  end as order_no, 
  name,
  sum(amount) as amount
from mytable
group by rollup(name, order_no);

BEGIN

FOR person_rec in totalByPerson
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(person_rec.order_no || '-'|| person_rec.name||' - '|| person_rec.amount );

END LOOP;

END;
```